# Google chart ordered by stack height

Tags: javascript, sorting, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to reorder my chart after inserting some data from a json file. I've tried to sort the data array without success.

There's any plugin or easy way to reorder the stacks and show the tallest first?

Heres my code:

```js
  var ChartHelper = {

   data: [],
   labels: [],
   datarray: [],

   init: function() {
    this.setupChart();
    this.bindEvents();
   },
   bindEvents: function() {

    // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
         google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

         // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
         google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(ChartHelper.drawChart);

         if (document.addEventListener) {
         window.addEventListener('resize', ChartHelper.resizeChart);
     }
     else if (document.attachEvent) {
         window.attachEvent('onresize', ChartHelper.resizeChart);
     }
     else {
         window.resize = ChartHelper.resizeChart;
     }

   },

   drawChart: function() {
     // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

          ChartHelper.data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ChartHelper.datarray);

          

          // Set chart options
          ChartHelper.options = {
           title: 'Usuários influentes',
     width: '100%',
           height: 900,
           chartArea: {width: '85%', top: 50,left:10},
           
           stacked: true
         };
        

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          ChartHelper.chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('myChart'));
          ChartHelper.chart.draw(ChartHelper.data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(ChartHelper.options));



          

   },

   getBrands: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "./data/brands.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
     ChartHelper.brands = [];
     $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       
       if(ChartHelper.labels.indexOf(val.name) === -1){
        ChartHelper.labels.push( val.name );
        ChartHelper.brands.push(val);
       }
       
     });
      }
    });

    // push brands
    Object.keys(ChartHelper.brands).filter(function(index) {
           ChartHelper.datarray.push([ChartHelper.brands[index].name]);
         });
    
   },

   getUsers: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "./data/users.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
     ChartHelper.users = [];
       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         ChartHelper.users.push(val);
         ChartHelper.setupDatasets(val,key);
       });
      }
    });

    // push users
    var users = [];
    Object.keys(ChartHelper.users).filter(function(index) {
           users.push(ChartHelper.users[index].login.username);
         });
    users.unshift('Marcas');
         ChartHelper.datarray.unshift(users);
   },

   getInteractions: function() {
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "./data/interactions.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
     ChartHelper.interactions = [];
       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         ChartHelper.interactions.push(val);
       });
      }
    });

   },

   setupDatasets: function(user,i) {
    var totalInte;
    var userdata = [];
    var j = i+1;
    $.each(ChartHelper.labels, function( key, val ){
     totalInte = 0;
     $.each(ChartHelper.interactions, function( key2, val2 ){
      if(user.id == val2.user) {
       Object.keys(ChartHelper.brands).filter(function(index) {
           if(ChartHelper.brands[index].id == val2.brand && ChartHelper.brands[index].name == val)
            totalInte++;
       });
      }
     });

     
     if(totalInte > 0)
      userdata = totalInte;
     else
      userdata = '';

     
     
     ChartHelper.datarray[key][j] = totalInte;
    
    });

    

    
    
    

    
   },

   setupChart: function() {
    

          ChartHelper.datarray = [];

    this.getBrands();
    this.getInteractions();
    this.getUsers();  
          
   },

   getRandColor: function(){
       var brightness = 4;
       var rgb = [Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256];
       var mix = [brightness*51, brightness*51, brightness*51]; //51 => 255/5
       var mixedrgb = [rgb[0] + mix[0], rgb[1] + mix[1], rgb[2] + mix[2]].map(function(x){ return Math.round(x/2.0)})
       return "rgb(" + mixedrgb.join(",") + ")";
   },
   
   resizeChart: function() {
       ChartHelper.chart.draw(ChartHelper.data, ChartHelper.options);
   }


  };


  $(document).ready(function() {
   // ready
   ChartHelper.init();
  });
```

Tried many options for different charts and I'm still reading the docs to find a solution, please help me!

Here's a demo:
[DEMO](https://emancipa.com.br/git/chart-stack/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort the data table before drawing the chart...

```
    // sort data table on value column
    ChartHelper.data.sort([{column: 1}]);

    ChartHelper.chart.draw(ChartHelper.data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(ChartHelper.options));
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added the "desc" param in order to show the tallest first:
ChartHelper.data.sort([{column: 1, desc: true}]);